# JavaScript - Saving the selected items after button press

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

So I am unsure of how to have it where I have a button that on the press saves the new selected as the page selected (on refresh) for example:

> User 1 (Default Selected)
>
> User 2
>
> Save

on selecting User 2 and pressing Save

> User 2 (Default Selected)
>
> User 1
>
> Save

I don't know where to begin with JavaScript however here is the HTML Code example, there are multiple options and there are about 12 dropdown boxes this will need to apply to as well

Here is the HTML example:

```
<option value="0">User 1</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">User 2</option>
<option value="2">User 3</option>
<option value="3">User 4</option>
```

There are a few of these in the html but i would like to have them all save on the same button pressed if possible so that when you next refresh the page it will show the ones that you last selected and saved instead of what was there before.

I don't think local-storage would work in this situation either

Thanks.

Comment: Why not local storage? Either that or a cookie would do the trick. Even better, do it server-side if possible.

Comment: you can use localstorage o session storage is the best way if you don't have the server-side possibilities

Comment: It is on a sharepoint site and it will need to be seen publically as well from what i read up on local storage it didnt look like it fit the job but then again im not experienced with javascript really.